# My first project: Editing an .img file, guidance wanted

Tags: c++, file-io, visual-studio-2012

Note: The only programming experience i have can be found here(cs50.tv).
I know some deal about c, and i have visual studio express 2012 running. I want to dive into making stuff and currently i am aiming to create a mod install for a game (Gta San, in case anybody cares).

Essentially the file just need to open a .img file(gta3.img to be exact) and remove/replace/append files to it.
I am thinking that the best way to learn programming is to program, and i am hoping that i can get some help about it.

Please tell me what kind of concepts should i research so as to get started? (Excluding c++ syntax, OOP or using visual studio. I know about em already and working my butt off on em. Havent slept for over 36 hours..).

Comment: What kind of .img file? An ISO? A binary file?

Comment: You need to learn to walk before you attempt space travel

Comment: You should probably spend some time reading the FAQ to learn how to properly ask questions here. An awful lot of your previous questions got closed and you'll otherwise soon be banned from asking more.

Comment: And indeed, before you learn to walk, you must first create the universe.

Comment: Aayush, would you care to elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to do? A "mod install for a game", can you be more specific? An installer for a game mod? Or what? Please, give some more details and I'm quite certain there are plentiful of people that can help you in any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know to help you at this specific question. However you have right that you have to do something in order to learn how to code. At this part i would sugest visit http://www.code.org/ . This is a great website, and it is really helpful at helping you learn how to code, but also to create mobile application, or a website.

Sorry I do not know how to guide you at this problem